# getParameterByName get values store in cookie

Tags: jquery, variables, cookies

I'm trying to grab values in the location.queryString Object one I get the two values i want to store them in a cookie that I can then pass over to the api at checkout process.

```
function getParameterByName( name ){
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)", 
regex = new RegExp( regexS ),
results = regex.exec( window.location.search );
if( results === null ){
return "";
} else{
return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
}

var mc_emailId =  getParameterByName('mc_eid');
var mc_campaignId =  getParameterByName('mc_cid');  
var mccookie = new Array([]);
document.cookie = mccookie;
alert(document.cookie);
```

I stopped for a sec because I don't think I'm doing this correctly so for what I'm wanting to accomplish. In the location.queryString there is two values i need to pass over to the cookie. mc_eid and mc_cid all the code works fine but I'm not sure how to target those.

**Update from advice below**

```
  // Mail Chimp ID's Stored in Variable
  function getParameterByName( name ){
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)", 
    regex = new RegExp( regexS ),
    results = regex.exec( window.location.search );
    if( results === null ){
      return "";
    } else{
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
  }

  var mc_emailId =  getParameterByName('mc_eid');
  var mc_campaignId =  getParameterByName('mc_cid');

  mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId;
  document.cookie = mccookie;

  var days = 30;
  var d = new Date();    
  d.setTime(d.getTime()  + (days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires =";expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = mccookie + expires + "; path=/";
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie string has a name and a value for  each cookie like `name=value; name2=value;`

For your code you could do something like

```
mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emaild + "; mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId;
document.cookie = mccookie;
```

Alerting document.cookie would alert the whole cookie string. 
[W3Schools has some functions you could use to get a cookie by name or set one.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

**To set expire date**

```
var days = 30;
var d = new Date();    
d.setTime(d.getTime()  + (days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires =";expires="+d.toUTCString();
```

You will also want to use `path` to make the cookie accessible on the whole site. After you've set `expires` and `mccookie` as above you should finally set the cookie like this

`document.cookie = mccookie + expires + "; path=/";`

Comment: Ok that works great but when I change the page it no longer keeps the cookie stored. how can I fix this so the cookie stays for 30 days?

Comment: @gx2g in the page I linked, there is a function called setCookie that has code to make a date string given the amount of days. Then you add add to the cookie string like `expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC` , I added code to answer

Comment: do you mean like this here?

Comment: in that example do I change cname or leave it. right now the cookie is being displayed on the home page but I can't get it to stay one I click on a product page. the cookie is empty on the next page.i can type mccookie in the console but no values are being returned just the names

Comment: Try adding `;path=/` to the cookie

Comment: Should be `document.cookie = mccookie + "; path=/";

Comment: I think I did it right like this,  mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_cid=" + "mc_campaignId; path=/";

Comment: @gx2g, your slightly off with where you put your quotes, your not getting the variable string the full thing should look like this after you set expires variable. `document.cookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_id=" + mc_campaignId + expires + "; path=/";`

Comment: can you update your answer so I can double check my work to make sure I'm folllowing you correctly please.

Comment: it's weird because in chrome console under resources I don't see the cookie at all but if I type in the console mcookie it shows the name and values.

Comment: @gx2g added everything to answer

Comment: can you refresh and check my updated section tell me if that looks right I'm testing it now.

Comment: @gx2g yes, only thing would be `document.cookie = mccookie;` is not required, you only need the `document.cookie = ...`  at the end

Comment: I noticed that i have a location.queryString with the object of the url path stored on home page. but as soon as i go to mens shoes the url changes and if I type in the console mccookie I only get the name "mc_eid=; mc_cid=" with no values. how come you think that is?

Comment: @gx2g when you change page, the cookie should be retrieved using `document.cookie` for example on whatever page you want to get the cookie do `mccookie = document.cookie;`

Comment: :) that's cool I tired that but it shows the value and the whole string actually on the home page but as soon as I go to a navigation tab and call the same thing mccookie = document.cookie; it shows the whole cookie string and the values are missing this time around. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102755/discussion-between-gx2g-and-sawyer-charles).